# Navigate to another man page within a man page

Tags: linux, manpage

Say I have given `man ls`.

Within this man page I found another function/keyword that I wanted to check up. Say I found the function name by doing `/fun_name`. Now I want to see the man page of this `fun_name`. Only way I know of is to quit to present man page and do `man fun_name`.

Is there a shortcut?

Comment: When inside `man` you could press `h` to see a detailed list of commands available and their shortcut.

Comment: Thanks @legends2k. I found this option `!command`. And if I do `!man fun_name`, it will work.

Comment: +1 for finding help yourself; nice, good to know :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When inside the `man` page, do the following:

- Press `!` followed by a valid shell command.
- For example : `!man cat`
- You can exit by pressing `q`
- It would say, `!done  (press RETURN)`. You can either press `ENTER` key or continue pressing `q` to get out of the multiple `man` pages

Comment: This is not satisfactory at all since you're manually typing the page name. It's almost equivalent to quitting the process and typing the same exact command in the terminal directly. The only thing you really get is a navigation history, but using a proper manpager for page links is widely more efficient, and exists. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77241139/16974218)

Answer (score 1):

The `man` executable doesn't provide this functionality.

You can however use `w3mman` which will allow you to:

- Follow links to other pages with `Enter` while browsing manpages in the terminal
- Cycle through all manpages links in the current page with `Tab`
- Go back to previous page with `Shift+B`

It's an other executable but still very similar to `less` (the pager actually used (by default) by `man`), so the usage will stay familiar while being able to navigate through manpages at ease. It is provided by the package [`w3m`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/W3m)* on most distributions.

PS: Type `Shift+H` to see all `w3m` keybindings

*which is a terminal web browser, and the pager actually used by `w3mman`